# dbpedia resource for wiki portals

Tags: dbpedia

I have two questions:

1) Whats the corresponding dbpedia resource for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events/Sports

2) How could I find that information myself in future. I know for regular wiki articles, I just need to make an underscore string for the resource. I dont know how to do it for "Portals" as in the link above

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general pattern to get the DBpedia URI for a Wikipedia URI is very simple: replace `/wiki/` by `/resource/` and `.wikipedia.org` by `.dbpedia.org`, except for English replace `en.wikipedia.org` by `dbpedia.org`.

Examples:

`http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlino` -> `http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Berlino`
`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin` -> `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin`

(Note that the distinction between IRIs and URIs in RDF adds a little more complexity, but that's for a different question...)

DBpedia only generates URIs for some Wikipedia namespaces - currently only for the main article namespace and the `Category:` namespace, I think. URIs for `Portal:` and other namespaces occur only as targets of links (in files like page_links_en.nt). If such DBpedia URIs were extracted, they would look very similar to the others. In your example, the DBpedia URI would be

`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Portal:Current_events/Sports`

But would it make sense to have Linked Data URIs for Wikipedia portals? I don't know. It seems there is not much data to be extracted from these pages. And they don't seem to be a good match for Linked Data resource URIs. Such URIs usually represent a *thing* in the real world. Or maybe not so real, but still a thing...